# Assistance with advanced Git Cloning

Tags: git, bash, github

i am very much a novice with GIT and would like some assistance.

I understand the cloning process basics, however i have a GIT repo that i would like to clone and keep updated using a bash script, however i am not sure how to get this done.

Here is the issue: If i use the following command "git clone https://github.com/trakt/Plex-Trakt-Scrobbler"  I get what is the root folder - what i actually need is the branch inside (trakttv.bundle) to be the root of the git and then i can simply script a cron job to do a git pull to update.

Can someone advise me it is possible to clone the trakttv.bundle directly to allow me to directly update this?  Hope this makes sense - please let me know if you would like more information.

Update: On further investigation i find that Traktv.bundle is not a branch of the repo - it is a folder structure under the master branch.  I have review a bunch of sites, examples and docos and can't seem to get clone just the subfolder

Cheers,
Darren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what I actually need is the <del>branch</del> inside ([`Trakttv.bundle`](https://github.com/trakt/Plex-Trakt-Scrobbler/tree/master/Trakttv.bundle/Contents)) to be the root of the git and then I can simply script a cron job to do a `git pull` to update.

It is best to separate:

- the git layout [`Plex-Trakt-Scrobbler/Trakttv.bundle/Contents`](http://Trakttv.bundle/Contents), within which you can do a `git pull`
- the deployment layout (where you want a folder referencing directly `Trakttv.bundle`, not `Plex-Trakt-Scrobbler/Trakttv.bundle`)

For the second case, use a symlink for getting a folder pointing to `Plex-Trakt-Scrobbler/Trakttv.bundle`

```
cd /my/path
ln -s /path/to/Plex-Trakt-Scrobbler/Trakttv.bundle
ls
# output:
Trakttv.bundle
```

In /my/path, you would see directly `Trakttv.bundle`, but you would go (with the cron job) in `/path/to/Plex-Trakt-Scrobbler/Trakttv.bundle` to do the `git pull`.

Comment: Hi VonC, i have already attempted your suggestion (thank you for your reply), however when i run -git clone https://github.com/trakt/Plex-Trakt-Scrobbler/Trakttv.bundle/Contents trakttv.test `code`I get the following error: Cloning into 'trakttv.test'...
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/trakt/Plex-Trakt-Scrobbler/Trakttv.bundle/Contents/' not found

Comment: @Darren yes, you need to clone `https://github.com/trakt/Plex-Trakt-Scrobbler` somewhere, then make a symlink to `<somewhere>\Plex-Trakt-Scrobbler\Trakttv.bundle`.

Comment: Hi VonC (thanks again for your reply) that does get the outcome in an indirect way and will do what is needed, however is there not a way to clone the remote subfolder to a new local root?  something like pull down the content folder inside the trakttv.bundle folder on git hub to a new local trakttv.bundle folder?

Comment: No, clone, then symlink is much safer than trying any other trick

Answer (score 0):

```
git clone --branch trakttv.bundle https://github.com/trakt/Plex-Trakt-Scrobbler
```

you are able to specify a branch which will be checked out after the clone.

This is in essence

```
git clone https://github.com/trakt/Plex-Trakt-Scrobbler
git checkout trakttv.bundle
```

Comment: Hi Alistair,Thank you very much for your replay and the syntax makes sense to me, however when i test this, if get the following error.

git clone --branch trakttv.bundle https://github.com/trakt/Plex-Trakt-Scrobbler
Cloning into 'Plex-Trakt-Scrobbler'...
fatal: Remote branch trakttv.bundle not found in upstream origin